# Do follow link redirection

Tags: seo, google-search, redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect

I am new to SEO and using WordPress. I got a do-follow back link from a website. The link's structure was `/2018/03/03/abc/`. After that I changed the permalink structure. So the link became `/abc`  and now the previous URL redirects to the new one. But Google doesn't crawl the previous URL because of the 301 redirect. I am not able to contact that website to change the URL of the do follow link. Does this changed URL count as a back link or not? If not, how should I fix this?

Comment: Does your 301 redirect to the current content page? Or to the root page?

Comment: It redirects to the current content page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the old URL 301-redirects to the new URL, you have no more work to do. Click on the old link on their site to double check that it redirects to your new URL. The 301 redirect passes link juice from the old URL to the new URL, so your site will keep the SEO gained from the backlink.